# How to run Flutter by url schema?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Like I have a url: myapp://abc/, and I want to run my Flutter App once the schema is detected. I know only one way to solve this, is adding Intent-Filter in AndroidManifest.xml.
I'm not so interested in writing different codes on both Android and iOS. So is there any way to solve the problem only use Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this plugin https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uni_links.

It allows you to write code to handle the app url in flutter, however you still need to setup your Intent-Filter in AndroidManifest.xml and your url schemes in Info.plist

Comment: I am interested in doing the same thing, when the user want to confirm email addressress.My problem is, how to create the URL? <a href="myapp://www.google.com">Confirm</a>